# How to return JSON response of saved from a REST API (ExpressJS) when button clicked using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, express

I was trying to add a user form my React front-end application to my rest API using fetch API. It did save data to the database. But I didn't get the `res.status(201).json({"user" : user})` JSON response from the API when I clicked the button. I want a response like:

```js
{
  "username": "Verginia",
  "_id": "BkNjV359I"
}
```

*This is my React code for the form button click*

```
async function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const body = { username }
    let response 
    try {
        response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/users', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
    console.log(response)
}
```

*This is my form code ( I took Button and Input as separate components*

```
   <form className="d-flex">
       <Input 
           className="form-control" 
           type="text" 
           name="username"
           value={username}
           placeholder="Enter Username"  
           onChange={handleChange}   
       />
       <Button 
           onClick={handleClick} 
           className="btn btn-success" 
           type="submit" />
   </form>
```

*This is my server side post code*

```
.post(async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body.username.length !== 0) {
        const newUser = new User({
            userid: randomstring.generate({
                length: 9,
                readable : true,
                charset: "alphanumeric",
            }),
            username: req.body.username
        })
        await User.find({username: newUser.username}, (err, result) => {
            if (result.length) {
                res.status(409).json({
                    message: "Username already exists! Try a different username"
                })
            }else {
                User.create(newUser, (err, user) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        res.status(201).json({"user" : user})
                    }else {
                        res.status(400).json({"error" : error.message})
                    }
                })
            }
        })

    }else {
        next(new Error("Body can't be empty"))
    }

})
```

Comment: what's the output of ` console.log(response)`

Comment: This was my console output for `console.log(response)`
`Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:5000/api/users", redirected: false, status: 201, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
__proto__: Headers
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 201
statusText: "Created"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:5000/api/users"
__proto__: Response`

Comment: try to `console.log(response.json())`

Comment: Now,
`Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
catch: ƒ catch()
constructor: ƒ Promise()
finally: ƒ finally()
then: ƒ then()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"
__proto__: Object
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Object
user:
userid: "tSkQp6xwg"
username: "Albert Rio"
__v: 0
_id: "5ebd39889eb27c22347f1204"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object`

Comment: okay try this : `console.log(await response.json())`

Comment: If you have a promise you might still be using my original answer, I did update it after Vivek's suggestions so double check you're using the new version of my answer

Comment: Oh and from my answer, is should be ```console.log(response_json)``` not ```console.log(response)```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But, it is not showing on the browser when I clicked the button. How can I show the response on the browser? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your handleClick function doesn't look right to me, it should be:

```js
async function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const body = { username }
    let response;
    let response_json;
    try {
        response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/users', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        })
        response_json = await response.json()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

EDIT: Adjusted for commenters advise. While my original answer would actually work, this new way should also work with async/await

EDIT2: I just realised your backend link is over http, not https. I'm not actually sure if you're getting a response at all, but if you're not it could be that since you're POSTing using fetch, either CORS is blocking you on the backend or the pre-flight check (OPTIONS) done by fetch isn't being answered.

Comment: remove before someone downvotes, OP is already using `async await` so need of `.then`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I've adjusted my answer

Comment: But it still not returning the expected answer. And keep remaining at what it was before.

Comment: @Adam Your answer also output `Promise {<pending>} __proto__: Promise catch: ƒ catch() constructor: ƒ Promise() finally: ƒ finally() then: ƒ then() Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise" __proto__: Object [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved" [[PromiseValue]]: Object user: userid: "tSkQp6xwg" username: "Albert Rio" __v: 0 _id: "5ebd39889eb27c22347f1204" __proto__: Object __proto__: Object`

Thanks for that. But can you please tell me why not my server `res.json()`  is not triggering. And can you please tell me how to show the response to the browser as I mentioned the way I want.